# Loading screen between states

Tags: java

I am developing a game in java which has many states and textures for each state that are being load when the state is changing, every time I am going from one state to another, the screen pauses for something like a second and then the new textures appear.

I know it is normal and I am OK with this fact so I thought maybe I should add some sort of loading screen, the only proble, is that I don't really know how to...

I thought maybe creating a new thread that operates only when I need to load the textures but thread are kind of new to me and I am having difficulties with it. Can anyone help me with my idea or maybe suggest another idea?

Comment: Threads are exactly what you want to use. And I suggest you check out some tutorials on Threads in Java. I would have done it the way that when you are about to change the states, I would create a new Thread which would draw some Loading info and after the state is loaded, I would kill the loading Thread

Comment: It's hard to help you as we have 0 information about your code. Please add more details and show us what you've tried

Comment: @Coreggon Thanks for the approval, I was actually able to handle it and throughout my research I learned how great threads are and how to use them.

Comment: That was exactly my intention:)